# Projected CRS interfering with Spatial Analyses?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

I am working with two polygon shapefiles, one of which is a buffer around the other, and a point shapefile in a project set to EPSG:54016. All layers are correctly reprojected and in the same CRS, OTF is turned off.
I am now trying to identify/select all points that lay within the buffer zone, but none of the tools work for me. Points in Polygon tool won't even start, Spatial Query and Select by location freeze the system.

I cannot find any information about it on the internet.

I wonder if anyone ever encountered this problem or if I am lacking knowledge about the procedures involved?

Comment: Have you set their projections in properties or did you use save as to reproject? If you just changed the projection in the layer properties then it will fail. Also if you have invalid geometries it will fail

Comment: I have saved them in the new projection and made sure everything is correct. Otherwise usually tools like Points in Polygon will yell at you telling you the CRS do not match. I wonder if the associated spatial reference information might be causing the problem - the shapefile I buffered comprised the whole globe and I fear that the extends of the buffer go beyond this information. Do you have any experience with that? Thanks a lot!